# Redirect STDERR and STDOUT to log with nohup

Tags: ruby, nohup

I'm trying to run a few scripts remotely from a Ruby script and am at a loss with redirecting the output of the command to a file.

I'm sshing to another server, running a command with `nohup`, and trying to write the output of the command to a file. The file gets written, but no content is in the file.

Here's an example of the command:

```
system("ssh server \"cd /tmp; nohup ./myscript.ksh 2>&1 >> output.txt &\"")
```

Any ideas? This should be working from what I understand.

Comment: `system("ssh server \"cd /tmp; nohup ./myscript.ksh >> output.txt 2>&1 &\"")`

Comment: I think @Aguardientico is correct about changing the order of the redirects. In addition, I'd recommend using single-quotes for your command for readability: `'ssh server "cd /tmp; nohup ./myscript.ksh 2>&1 >> output.txt &"'` works as well as what you used, without having to escape the double-quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Arguardientico's solution worked:

```
system("ssh server \"cd /tmp; nohup ./myscript.ksh >> output.txt 2>&1 &\"")
```